# installing gdal in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, gdal

I have been trying to import "gdal" in PyCharm for a couple of hours now, but without success and I do not know any further now.

In the Anaconda Powershell I installed gdal:

`conda install gdal`,

and that seemed to work, I get "# All requested packages already installed". Also, when I hit `conda list`, gdal is listed as one of the packages (gdal 2.3.3).

Now, normally it works in PyCharm then. However, this time it does not. What I tried:

- In PyCharm, I hovered over `import gdal` and tried to install the package, but without success.
- In PyCharm, Settings -> Project Interpreter -> "+" -> tried to install the "GDAL" package there, but without success as well.
- In PyCharm, Settings -> Project Interpreter -> "Show All" -> "Show paths for the selected interpreter" -> there I added the path to the "gdal-2.3.3-py37hdf43c64_0" directory ("C:...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs"), but without success.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use this conda interpreter in PyCharm? What error do you receive when installing gdal fails?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use conda anywhere would be to install a conda environment with the following commands followed by using the same environment in the pycharm.

**Conda environment install commands:**

```
conda create -n gdal python=3.7
activate gdal
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

**Setting conda environment in the pycharm:**

```
-> Go to Preferences / settings in pycharm 
-> Search for `python interpreter` 
-> Click on the drop down and then click on show all
-> Click on the + symbol to add the environment
-> Click on Conda environment in the left panel and select existing environment
-> Select the exact path of python3.7 (or other version) where the environment is installed (/opt/anaconda3/envs/gis/bin/python3.7 - in case of mac)
```

That should get the job done.